# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://script.google.com/macros/ - has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a Spreadsheet, I created script.google.com code as web API to export spread sheet data as json but when write code to read json has problem "has been blocked by CORS policy

```
var dataJSON;
    

    function viewVillages(){
          
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         
var url = "script.google.com";
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 1  ) {
                console.log("1");
                
            }
            if (this.readyState == 2  ) {
                console.log("2");
                
            }
            if (this.readyState == 3  ) {
                console.log("3");
                
            }
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log("4");
                
                var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                myFunction(myArr);
                
            }
        };
         
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        
        function myFunction(arr) {
            dataJSON=arr;
        }
        
    }
```

code for publish web app API
i publish this as web app API , by anyone can access this app,
this link for result

https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=idpffu-SYlDxC7EuWBf-NqgCGhMPNeiXeBQUt-Tk-dDFoqb6JYzKvNyw405zrlyQEDgaTlGUksHOTbbV5Aj9STHlRS9FtMxjm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnNhRObYMMbRvDsIN0NCwYbNGFGtS5GcRpQ0e15R5Rfx0Jy77eUQpR9E0M2qu45i7T6drUwBK3ZY_&lib=MMMohOFXoOCvrcVJ1jiPfgJKNXc8Lw_h0

```
function doGet(e){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
 var sheetgoogle = ss.getSheetByName("labs"); 
 return getUsers(sheetgoogle); 
}

function getUsers(sheetgoogle){
  var ps = {};
  var dataArrayGoogle = [];
var rowsGoogle = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetgoogle.getLastRow()-1, sheetgoogle.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for(var i = 0, l= rowsGoogle.length; i<l ; i++){
    var dataRowGoogle = rowsGoogle[i];
    var recordSheet={} ;
    recordSheet[0] = dataRowGoogle[0];
    recordSheet[1] = dataRowGoogle[1];
    dataArrayGoole.push(recordSheet);
  }  
  ps.user = dataArrayGoogle;
  var result = JSON.stringify(ps);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  
}
```

Comment: Published as `Anyone even anonymous`? Show your `doGet()` and `doPost()`

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the code and how your web-app is published. See [ask] and [mre]

Comment: @TheMaster  I edited my question, please help me , thanks

Comment: 1. When you access the web-app api, is it recorded in Google apps script logs? Script editor>View> executions>clear `Ran as me` filter at top 2. To confirm, you published as `Anyone`**`even anonymous`**? 3. Published link should be script.google.com .. where did you get script.googleusercontent.com?

Comment: Kindly add a answer in the answer box below. See [answer]